# What is going on in Apple's first example of an optional value in the Swift tour?

Tags: ios, swift, option-type

In Apple's "Swift Tour" introduction to swift, they give the following example of optionals:

```
var optionalString: String? = "Hello"
optionalString == nil

var optionalName: String? = "John Appleseed"
var greeting = "Hello!"
if let name = optionalName {
    greeting = "Hello, \(name)"
}
```

Does the second line serve any purpose?

Comment: The Guided Tour chapter can be downloaded as a Playground file, an then the value of an expression (in this case: `false`) is shown in the right column.

Comment: Without playground it doesn't make sense, because its a comparision for `nil`, not an assignment.

Comment: May be they forgot to put comment sign before that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
optionalString == nil
```

is an expression, and in a compiled program the expressions's value (in this case: `false`)
is ignored.

However, the Swift Guided Tour is [downloadable as a Playground file](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/GuidedTour.playground.zip), and in a Playground
any expression value is displayed in the right column.

[image]

You are encouraged to edit the code listings and see the the results immediately.

Answer (score 0):

The first bit of code

```
var optionalString: String? = "Hello"
optionalString == nil
```

Is just comparing the optional to nil, when this code is run in a playground `false` will show up on the right hand side.

The second chunk.

```
var optionalName: String? = "John Appleseed"
var greeting = "Hello!"
if let name = optionalName {
    greeting = "Hello, \(name)"
}
```

Is using what is called optional binding. The author could just as easily have written

```
var optionalName: String? = "John Appleseed"
var greeting = "Hello, \(optionalName!)"
```

Note the exclamation mark at the end of  `optionalName!` this is whats known as Forced Unwrapping, In this particular case it would have been fine since we set the value of the variable immediately before hand. In general though Forced Unwrapping is considered to be unsafe since you're basically saying that you know better than the compiler. Forced Unwrapping is sometimes affectionally referred to as the crash operator ;)

You can find the section on optionals [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/TheBasics.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014097-CH5-XID_496)

Comment: "Is just demonstrating that optionals can be set to nil". No, it's not an assignment, it's a comparison that checks if the optional string is nil (which would return false).

Answer (score 0):

```
var optionalString: String? = nil
optionalString == nil
```

change your  code as above,and you can see the use of second line.
It tell you the optionalValue can be set to nil,and compare to nil.Most of the classes can't do these.